# Why are UITableView Frames Different for Initial and Filtered Search Results?

Tags: uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have a view controller that displays some user-entered items. In that view controller, I configure an `UISearchController` and a separate view controller to display the search results:

```swift
private lazy var filteredItemsViewController: UITableViewController = {
    let controller = UITableViewController(style: .plain)
    controller.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
    return controller
}()

private lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
    let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.filteredItemsViewController)
    controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
    return controller
}()
```

I have noticed that the table view for the initial data has the expected frame. However, the table view that displays the filtered results has some extra space above the initial cell. It seems to match the height of the status bar, but I can't figure out how to remove the extra space. I have tried setting the frame of the table view of the filtered results, but that did not solve it.

Here is a side-by-side comparison of the table views:

[image: Screenshot of comparison of table view frames]

What am I missing that will allow me to remove the extra space above the initial cell in the table view that displays search results?